# Программа для высчитывания возможных вариаций расположения фишек на доске

Tags: python, python-3.x, комбинаторика

Всем привет! Недавно в голову пришла идея сделать одну очень занимательную прогу на питоне: Есть фишки и есть доска 8х8 ячеек. Пользователь вводит кол-во фишек (от 1 до 64, 1 фишка = 1 ячейка на доске) и после подсчитывается количество возможных вариантов расположений этих фишек на доске. Пример:
Ввод: 1,
Вывод: 64.
Долго думал как эту программу написать и в силу своей неопытности(учу питон всего неделю) так и не додумался.
Буду очень благодарен если поможете с решением.

Comment: [Число сочетаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). `import math; print(math.comb(64, 2))`.

Comment: С наступающим! Пусть в новом году на все ваши вопросы ответы будут находится за шесть минут!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну так примерно так оно и есть :) - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12129/195342

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Написал простенькую програмку с этой строкой, работает вполне трезво. Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне всё таки удалось написать программу(не без помощи комментаторов), она на мое удивление довольно простая. Кому надо оставлю тут:

```
import math

def start(chip_numb):
    combinations = math.comb(64, chip_numb)
    print(f"Количество комбинаций: {combinations}")

while True:
    chip_numb = int(input("Кол-во фишек(от 1 до 64): "))
    if chip_numb < 1 or chip_numb > 64:
        print('Введите кол-во фишек в пределах указанного диапазона')
    else:
        start(chip_numb)
```